# How to fix a MSVC library that's corrupt?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've been using Visual Studio 2017 on a Mac running Parallels for a few years. It's been relatively smooth sailing until today.

I was building my latest build and got this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64\libcpmt.lib :
fatal error LNK1127: library is corrupt
[V:\Programming\MyPlugin\Builds\VisualStudio2017-64\MyPlugin_VST.vcxproj]
```

Being mostly a Mac guy, I haven't run into this before and not sure what to do. I assume I need to reinstall that library, but not sure how.

Comment: Just reinstall. Most of the Microsoft development tools have a non-destructive "Reinstall" or "Fix installation"-type option. Probably best also to run Windows Update afterwards to catch up on the latest version. (You might also have a virus or an about-to-die hard disk, so that's also worth a check, but outside of the scope of here: https://SuperUser.com would be better?)

Comment: Thanks. I started a reinstall and one of the options was to Repair my current installation...which did the trick. Thanks again.